# Single tenant to multi-tenant

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-active-directory

I have a website MVC 5 with a single tenant. I use single tenant but some users log on my website with a different tenant.

I have this error: AADSTS50020: User account .

CAN you help me please?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :)

Comment: How are they able to do that? If you define your authority as the single-tenant authority (i.e. it contains your tenant id), then they should not hit this problem (unless they modify the URL manually).

Comment: Could you provide the full error information?

Comment: error :The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

Comment: I create a  website with a multiple tenant but i have 400 error...

Answer (score 1):

> I have this error: AADSTS50020: User account .

If you don't update your website to be multi-tenant, upon other tenant users want to log on your website, it will prompt this same error.

> I create a website with a multiple tenant but i have 400 error.

For the multi-tenant, you need to change your endpoint from your tenant (like `https://login.microsoftonline.com/contoso.onmicrosoft.com`) to be `common` (like `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common`). By this, the login request could be sent to an endpoint that multiplexes across all Azure AD tenants.

For the details, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant#update-your-code-to-send-requests-to-common).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.

How I have to modify my code :

```
  public partial class Startup
{
    private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
    private static string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
    private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
    private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
    private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

    public static readonly string Authority = aadInstance + tenantId;

    // This is the resource ID of the AAD Graph API.  We'll need this to request a token to call the Graph API.
    string graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net";

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = Authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                {

                   AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) => 
                   {
                       var code = context.Code;
                       ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                       string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                       AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                       AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                       code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);

                       return Task.FromResult(0);
                   }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If the answer is useful for you, please help mark it, thanks!